# I want people upload videos in my youtube channel without giving them access

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-data-api, video-upload

I am developing a application where i required to collect videos of users, i want them to upload videos to my youtube channel without giving them access, i have checked data api documentation for javascript and php, i used both but i found that all examples are required oauth 2.0 auth and videos only uploaded to person that is logging with their credentials.

is there anyway i can provide them functionality to upload video in my youtube channel using google javascript api ?

i have tried many sample from youtube data api documentation but i have not found any sample that user can upload video in my youtube channel, i have authorised my application to manage my channel but i didnt found documentation that without passing access of token how can user upload video to my channel

Comment: As far as I know the only secure workaround is to have a server that has the OAuth video upload token and this server allows users to upload videos to it. That way the server can afterwards upload these videos to YouTube.